# Prolog: Code Generation

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming, code-generation

What's the most idiomatic approach to output prolog code from a prolog program (as a side effect)?

For instance, in a simple case, I might want to write a Program that, given a text input, yields another Prolog program representing the text as a directed graph.

I understand this question is somewhat vague, but I've resigned to consulting Stackoverflow after failing to find a satisfying answer in the available Prolog Meta-Programming literature, which mostly covers applications of meta-circular interpreters.

If you feel this question might be better articulated some other way, please edit it or leave a comment.

Comment: At the very least, give a concrete example of the text input and the Prolog representation you want as output. A non-idiomatic approach that does that would also improve your question.

Comment: Generate the rules, assert them and use "listing/1" or similar: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=listing

Comment: Did you do some progress ? I'm also interested in automated code generation in Prolog (Ergo/Flora preferrably), but on mainstream languages (C++,..) Did you do some tries in area of code synthesis on hypergraph networks (opencog/hypergraphdb) ?

Comment: @DmitryPonyatov Unfortunately, I haven't had time to do much Prolog recently! Your work sounds really interesting.

Answer (score 5):

The *most idiomatic* way is always to **stay pure** and *avoid* side effects.

Let the toplevel do the writing for you!

To *generate* a Prolog program, you define a **relation** that says for example:

```
program(P) :- ...
```

and then states, in terms of logical relations, **what holds** about `P`.

For example:

```
program(P) :-
        P = ( Head :- Body ),
        Head = head(A, B),
        Body = body(A, B).
```

Example query and answer:

```
?- program(P).
P =  (head(_G261, _G262):-body(_G261, _G262)).
```

So, there's your program, produced in a pure way.

If you want to write it, use `portray_clause/1`:

```
?- program(P), portray_clause(P).
head(A, B) :-
        body(A, B).
...
```

This can be useful in a failure driven loop, to produce many programs automatically.

Answer (score 1):

[`writeq/1`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=writeq/1) (or [`format('~q', [...])`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=format/2)) produces output that can be read back. Usually you need also to put a full stop after a clause body. For instance, try

```
?- A_Clause = (X is 1+Y, write('X is '), write(X), nl), format('~q.~n', [A_Clause]).
```

Readability of code suffers from loosing variables 'nice names', but the functionality is there...

*edit*

as noted by @false, a space before the dot will avoid a bug in case the output term would finish with a dot

Comment: Rather unsafe this `'~q.~n'` with terms that clobber with the `.`

Comment: The safest choice to write Prolog code that can be read back is the standard `write_canonical/1-2` predicates.